# Leaflet map not showing up in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, leaflet

Here's my view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap',
    'leaflet',
    'text!templates/map/MapTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, Bootstrap, L, MapTemplate){

    var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.body',
        template: _.template(MapTemplate),
        render: function() {

            // Load the map template
            this.$el.html(this.template());

            // Create the map
            var map = L.map('map', {
                dragging: false
            });

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

            map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 15});

            function onLocationFound(e) {
                var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

                L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);

                L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
            }

            map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

            function onLocationError(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }

            map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
        }
    });

    return MapView;
});
```

And my underscore template just has a div in it with an ID of map. I'm not getting any errors in the console, and when I check the requests, it's actually downloading all of the tiles and everything, but none of them are getting rendered. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: How do you call `render`? Is there a `.body` element in the DOM?

Comment: @muistooshort `.body` does exist. I'm loading `#map` through the template before I create the map, as you can see. I'm wondering if this maybe has something to do with it. Render gets called from my router file. I guess I could post that if you need it.

Comment: Does Leaflet care about how big its element is? Google maps, for example, care so they don't display themselves properly if you attach them to an element that hasn't been added to the page yet; I'm wondering if perhaps Leaflet has similar issues. Try moving all the Leaflet binding stuff into a `setTimeout(1, function() {...})` and see what happens.

Comment: @muistooshort I just gave that a shot and it's still not rendering. However, I think you may be onto something with the element being added to the page later.

Comment: @muistooshort According to leaflet they don't have any trouble binding to elements that were added after the DOM was loaded. So I guess it has to be something else.

Comment: did you figure this one out. im in the exact same situation. using AMD. backbone, require, etc. actually, ihave a try catch around the L.map and it fails...

Comment: @GabeRainbow I did figure this out, but unfortunately I don't remember exactly what was wrong. However, I do recall it not really being related to anything that I've outlined here, otherwise I would have submitted it as an answer. All I can say is double check everything, and make sure you're shimming leaflet for use with Require.